# WxForms DateTime to Python DateTime

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, wxwidgets

I need to convert DateTime from WxWidget

```
Fri Sep 28 00:00:00 2018
```

To another format like :

```
28/09/18 20:35:00
```

But i can't find anything to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `wx.DateTime` Format()
i.e.

```
d=wx.DateTime.Now()
d
<wx.DateTime: "Sat Sep 29 10:35:28 2018">
d.Format('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
'29/09/18 10:35:28'
```

For the format options see `datetime` manual pages https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

For `wx.DateTime` options, see https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.DateTime.html

To generate an actual python datetime (as per your question heading):

```
f = d.Format('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(f,'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
x
datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 29, 10, 35, 28)
```

Comment: Thanks , this worked. I tryed use .Format() but i used in wrong place.